# PieChartModel's Title is missing when using setExtender("skinPie")

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

So when I use setExtender("skinPie") to apply the Barcelona skin to my chart it just simply does not show the title anymore. If I comment it out and use the default skin my title shows. Here's a code snippet:

```
compliance = new PieChartModel();

compliance.set("OK", complianceCount);
compliance.set("NOT OK", nonComplianceCount);

compliance.setExtender("skinPie"); //if i comment this out the title shows
compliance.setTitle("Compliance");
compliance.setLegendPosition("e");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is in your 'skinPie' function? And what are the versions you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje for your time, you can see the solution to my problem below. Turns out it was something silly I didn't notice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's a silly problem, I copied the Javascript from the Barcelona Theme's live demo and they opted to have their own  titles so they cleared the titles in the script, see below:

```
function skinPie() {
        this.cfg.shadow = false;
        this.cfg.title = ''; //********I just removed this*******//
        this.cfg.seriesColors = ['#03A9F4', '#E91E63', '#4CAF50', '#FFC107'];
        this.cfg.grid = {
            background: '#ffffff',
            borderColor: '#ffffff',
            gridLineColor: '#F5F5F5',
            shadow: false
        };
        this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
            rendererOptions: {
                textColor: '#666F77',
            }
        };
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            shadow: false,
            lineWidth: 1,
            markerOptions: {
                shadow: false,
                size: 7,
                style: 'circle'
            }
        }
}
```

Be sure to clear your browser's cache before testing again as it might let you think the change didn't affect anything but it actually did.